# Devise password recoverable module via ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, devise

I building a javascript frontend (ember) to a rails api, and I'm using devise for user authentication.

All works well, but the password reccovery is giving me a hard time. I looked at the `views/devise/password/edit.html.erb` in devise and the properties seem to be `password`, `new_password` and `password_reset_token`.

I'm catching the password reset token from the url that is emailed, and constructed the following ajax call from it:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/users/password.json', 
  type: 'PUT',
  data: {password: this.get('password'), password_confirmation: this.get('passwordconfirmation'), reset_password_token: this.get('content.reset_token')}
});
```

I can see the call gets accepted, but I'm getting a devise error that I can't understand. I think it has something to do with the `resource` that is passed back from the standard view, but I thought I covered that by the `/user` part in the ajax call.

All that I can find on the web is about login and change password, nothing about this bit.

The error I'm getting is:

```
Started PUT "/users/password.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-29 09:01:36 +0200
Processing by Devise::PasswordsController#update as JSON
  Parameters: {"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "reset_password_token"=>"[FILTERED]"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

NoMethodError - undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass:
  (gem) devise-2.1.2/lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb:125:in `reset_password_by_token'
  (gem) devise-2.1.2/app/controllers/devise/passwords_controller.rb:30:in `update'
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you share how you got the reset password token via JSON. I'm not able to do that.

Comment: @dwhite I don't get it via json. It get's send in an email within the confirmation link. Once a user clicks the link it goes back to my site and at that point I have the token.         ajax.request({
          url: '/api/v1/users/password.json',
          type: 'PUT',
          data: {'user[password]': this.get('password'), 'user[password_confirmation]': this.get('passwordconfirmation'), 'user[reset_password_token]': this.get('content.reset_token')}
        })

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was to wrap the properties in the resource (user in my case):

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/users/password.json',
  type: 'PUT',
  data: {'user[password]': this.get('password'), 'user[password_confirmation]': this.get('passwordconfirmation'), 'user[reset_password_token]': this.get('content.reset_token')}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

my way:

```
$.ajax({url: '/users/password', type: 'PUT', data: { password: $password,  password_confirmation: $password_confirmation, current_password: $current_password }});
```

You can try it if you didn't solve it......